# Transforming div using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code snippet:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".class").on("click",function(){
     $("#transform").removeClass();
     $("#transform").addClass("circle");
     })
    })
```

```css
 .circle { 
     width: 100px; 
     height: 100px; 
     background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
     -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
            <div id="transform">Transform me</div>
    </div>
```

i wanna transform my div into a circle using `css` and `js` but its not working on my end.

Comment: did you get any error on console.

Comment: Instead of `$(".class").on("click",function(){` it will be `$(".column").on("click",function(){`

Comment: Its now working, Thank you so much !

Answer (score 3):

Try this code snippet. This works for your requirement I guess.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click').on('click', function(){
      $("#transform").toggleClass('circle');
    })   
  })
```

```css
#transform {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    display: inline-blick;
    background: red;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column">
    <div id="transform"></div>
    <button class='click'>Click</button>
</div>
```

You can use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code. You are removing transform id in your code.

```
//front-end code
<div class="column">
        <div   class="transform obj">Transform me</div>
</div>

//css 
.circle { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: red; -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; 
}

//js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class").on("click",function(){
      $(".obj").removeClass('transform');
      $(".obj").addClass("circle");
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are this element with class `.class`

Comment: You didn't close the `removeclass('tranform("));`